# How do I save the screenshots and meta data before submitting ANDROID?

Tags: android, google-play

I do not have the final APK file yet but I want to start adding the screenshots and other information ahead of time. There is a "SAVE" button and I am assuming this should be possible but it's not allowing me to save without the APK AFAIK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upload a draft APK (never has to see the actual market) in order to get started.  The only thing that MUST be correct here is the package name your app will use, as this is needed to create the new record, and is read out of the APK file rather than allowing users to enter it manually.  Nothing else about the application has to even resemble what your final will be.

With the draft in place you can start updating all the other meta data and using the Save button to save your work.  When you upload the final APK file, you may then click Publish.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to upload all the information at the same time. This makes sense though, if you put an app on the market that people could search, but didn't actually include the apk...well that would just be super confusing to anyone on the market.

Comment: it makes sense that you cant SUBMIT without the APK- but you should be able to save your work without the apk

Answer (score 1):

You could save your draft with a draft APK and then make sure to update the APK with your final one before you publish.